# create a curved sidebar for user dashboard background

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar, curve

I would like to create a curved side bar for my dashboard panel. I've tried 2 ways:

- create a svg and path: that result was not good at all.
- create with js: the result was good but it was rasterized :|

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// Quadratic Bézier curve
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(280, 0);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(240, 90, 270, 150);
ctx.lineTo(320, 320);
ctx.lineTo(320, 0);
ctx.fillStyle = "#0984e3";
ctx.fill();
//
const hes = document.getElementById('hesam');
const ctxx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// Quadratic Bézier curve
ctxx.beginPath();
ctxx.moveTo(281, 0);
ctxx.quadraticCurveTo(240, 90, 280, 150);
ctxx.lineTo(320, 320);
ctxx.lineTo(320, 0);
ctxx.fillStyle = "#74b9ff";
ctxx.fill();
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
}

#hesam {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <canvas id="hesam"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

https://codepen.io/hessamr/pen/vYLzePX

How can I have this result with vectorized and have quality to use bg of a side bar.

Comment: why don't you create a normal square sidebar and give border-radius to it the way you want it to look

Comment: because the angle of the curve is limited and we can not implement this curve .